# Use mirage config file for both addon and base app in ember-cli-mirage 0.2.*

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am upgrading our desktop and mobile ember apps to mirage (`ember-cli-mirage`) 0.2.3, from an 0.1.* version. These two apps share a common addon which has a number of test helpers, including a mirage config.

In mirage 0.1.*, the config functions (e.g. the contents of `app/mirage/config.js` and `addon/mirage/config.js`, respectively) for both the base app and the addon were executed. In mirage 0.2.3, only the config function for the addon is used; the base app's config is apparently not detected (tested with `debugger` statements).

Does anyone know how to tell mirage to use both config files?

Comment: Do you need to modify ember-cli-mirage setting in the config/environment.js ? (see http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/configuration/)

Comment: @JonRed I did try setting the "directory" option, but it didn't seem to have any effect.